# Регулярное выражение проверка имени

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Для проверки правильности ввода имени в форму  используется регулярное выражение

```
/^[a-zA-Z'][a-zA-Z-' ]+[a-zA-Z']?$/
```

но оно проверяет только латинские символы, а русские считает как неправильные.
Подскажите, как исправить это выражение, чтобы оно проверяло и русские символы в том числе?

Comment: А украинские? А немецкие äöüß? А китайские?

Comment: а как тогда сделать чтобы просто была проверка, что введены символы, а не числа?

Comment: если вот так задам `^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9-_\.]{1,20}$` то это будет работать?

Comment: @VladD, это кстати вполне решаемо :-)  
Можно использовать posix регулярные выражения к строке в юникоде.Псевдокласс **[[alpha]]**

Comment: @ReinRaus а как это? можете объяснить поподробнее?

Comment: В JS никак. Он не поддерживает posix, можно PHP, Perl (список не полный).

Comment: @ReinRaus: я ж к этому и подводил ;-)

Comment: повтор вопроса - качайте Expresso

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавить `а-яА-Я` и модификатор `u`. Получится что-то вроде:

```
/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я'][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я-' ]+[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я']?$/u
```

Еще можно убрать проверку букв в верхнем регистре выполнив проверку без учета регистра (модификатор i). А потом подумать на тему `ё`, `і`, `ї` и всего иного, что не входит в `a-zа-я`.

*P.S.: Некоторые люди, во время решения одной проблемы думают: «Я знаю, я буду использовать регулярные выражения». Теперь у них две проблемы.*

Comment: а зачем u? это выражение используется в js коде `rx:{
         ".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я'][a-zA-Zа-яА-Я-' ]+[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я']?$/ ,target:'input'},` и если я добавляю u, то у меня вылезает ошибка

Comment: @Heidel, в JS, насколько я догадываюсь, ``u`` можете опустить :)

Comment: так все равно не подходит, как уже выше прокомментировали. как задать просто проверку, что введены буквы, а не числа? буквы при этом любые. из всех алфавитов.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы хотите чтобы у вас валидация не ругалась проверьте не только файл Forms.js, скорее всего у вас будет еще одна форма называемая TMforms.js *в которой будет строка возвращения значения*:

```
return /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'][a-zA-Z-а-яА-ЯёЁ' ]+[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ']?$/.test(this.value)
```

— а вот тут идет возвращение значений.

Будьте внимательны в файле forms.js лежит вот эта строка:

```
".name":{rx:/^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'][a-zA-Z-а-яА-ЯёЁ' ]+[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ']?$/,target:'input'},
```

— основная строка присвоения символов и букв.

А в файле TMforms.js лежит вот эта строка:

```
return /^[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ'][a-zA-Z-а-яА-ЯёЁ' ]+[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ']?$/.test(this.value)
```

— а вот тут идет возвращение значений.

Они должны быть идентичны!